# C# XNA как подключить базу данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, xna

Нужно подключить базу данных, в приоритете Microsoft Access, но можно и другие варианты
Как это можно осуществить? В WindowsForm был готовый компонент отвечающий за подключения базы данных, а как это реализовать здесь?

`System.Data`- не знает

Предлагали через <kbd>Вид</kbd>-><kbd>Другие окна</kbd>-><kbd>Источники данных</kbd>-><kbd>База данных</kbd> Но в выборе источников базы данных нет(Visual Studio 2015) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, подключение к базам данных в XNA, к сожалению, **сильно** ограничено (вроде как в целях безопасности). Потому, на просторах (в том числе и на спецресурсах по XNA) рекомендуют использовать специальные классы для хранения данных [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.aspx) (по сути - работа с файлами) или использовать SQLite.

Т.е. ответ на ваш вопрос - видимо, штатным образом, к сожалению, никак.

Answer (score 0):

Очень рекомендую технологию подключения к БД - Entity Framework.
Ты создаешь модель базы данных с нуля (Code First) или на основе существующей (Database First), и используя ее как контекст данный, работаешь с базой данных.
P.S. Устанавливается плагин через nuget, содержится в библиотеке System.Data.Entity

Comment: Entity Framework - это мощная (и тяжелая) библиотека, реализующая [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) и подходит далеко не для всех задач. Есть и аналоги ([Nhibernate](http://nhibernate.info/), [Linq To SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx), [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed)...) Но здесь речь идет о подключении БД в XNA проектах, а это несколько иная платформа, которая сама по себе накладывает ограничения на работу с БД, судя по всему, из соображений безопасности или еще по каким-то причинам, ведомым в Microsoft.

Comment: В продолжение: достоверно не могу сказать, будет ли работать Entity на XNA, но судя по тому, с чем сталкивался и по информации в сети - не будет, хотя на роль истины в последней инстанции не претендую. Нужно пробовать, равно как и с другими ORM-фреймворками (вряд ли, конечно, но а вдруг!?), при условии, что ORM-модель подходит для решения задач, разумеется.